# camel : Unable to read BODYSTRUCTURE

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am using Apache Camel mail to read emails from an account. But for a particular mail, it is stuck over there and throws an exception as "Unable to read BODYSTRUCTURE" . It also does not mark the mail as read. Any mail received after that are not read by the camel service.

> 317422 [Camel (emailToEWSContext) thread #0 - imaps://outlook.office365.com] WARN org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer - Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - Failed to extract body due to: Unable to load BODYSTRUCTURE. Exchange: Exchange[][MailMessage@0x55f69873]. Message: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage@7a97bfa9]
>   org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: Failed to extract body due to: Unable to load BODYSTRUCTURE. Exchange: Exchange[][MailMessage@0x55f69873]. Message: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage@7a97bfa9 at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailBinding.extractBodyFromMail(MailBinding.java:275)

Comment: Add more details to your question , code snippet etc..

Comment: the mail contains an attachment(filename containing special characters like ", . ;" etc). Apache camel mail server reads the mail. throws the above exception but did not mark the mail as read hence  subsequent emails are not been read by the camel mail service. the code crashes before it reaches my code for mail processing. the code consists of an XML. file containing configurations for apache camel mail service and call to subsequent bean for further processing of the mail.